# How to bind parameters to a raw DB query in Laravel that's used on a model?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, laravel, laravel-4

Re,

I have the following query:

```
$property = 
    Property::select(
        DB::raw("title, lat, lng, ( 
            3959 * acos( 
                cos( radians(:lat) ) * 
                cos( radians( lat ) ) * 
                cos( radians( lng ) - radians(:lng) ) + 
                sin( radians(:lat) ) * 
                sin( radians( lat ) ) 
            ) 
        ) AS distance", ["lat" => $lat, "lng" => $lng, "lat" => $lat])
    )
    ->having("distance", "<", $radius)
    ->orderBy("distance")
    ->take(20)
    ->get();
```

It doesn't work: `Invalid parameter number: mixed named and positional parameters`.

Does anyone know a trick or a workaround (I can obviously write the full query but prefer to use fluent builder).

Comment: Silly question - but the documentation doesn't use `" "` in any of its examples.  Have you tried singles?

Comment: @JamesBinford yup, tried all possible combinations, including ```%s```

Comment: You have 2 `:lat` in query but only binding 1

Comment: @davidstrachan doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: Models don't really exist. You meant "used on an instance". A model is just a blank template. In the Laravel world everyone's using the wrong terminology, "model" when they mean "instance".

Answer (score 116, accepted):

OK, after some experimenting, here's the solution that I came up with:

```
$property = 
    Property::select(
        DB::raw("title, lat, lng, ( 
            3959 * acos( 
                cos( radians(  ?  ) ) *
                cos( radians( lat ) ) * 
                cos( radians( lng ) - radians(?) ) + 
                sin( radians(  ?  ) ) *
                sin( radians( lat ) ) 
            )
       ) AS distance")
    )
    ->having("distance", "<", "?")
    ->orderBy("distance")
    ->take(20)
    ->setBindings([$lat, $lng, $lat,  $radius])
    ->get();
```

Basically, `setBindings` has to be called on the query. Wish this was documented!

Comment: +1 Was looking for this exact answer...including the map radius query. Thanks!

Comment: setBindings doesn't appear to support PDO's named parameters :/

Comment: If you are working over a relation, for instance, you should use `addBinding` instead of `setBindings` to avoid overwrite relation bindings.

Comment: This is the signature of `setBindings(array $bindings, $type = 'where')`. If you would have had a binding in your WHERE clause, those would've been overwritten. You should specify that your bindings are for the SELECT portion of your query.
`->setBindings([$lat, $lng, $lat,  $radius], 'select')`

Comment: Worked for me also, although it didnt play nicely with ->where(), so I had to bind that too

Comment: Note that the bindings are positional only. You can still use named bindings for clarity in the code, such as `:radians`, but they will be treated as unnamed, i.e. `?`.

Answer (score 45):

Old question, but if we have to repeat a variable, we have to change its key value in the bindings array.

```php
    $property = Property::select(
        DB::raw("title, lat, lng, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(:lat) ) * 
        cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(:lng) ) + 
        sin(radians(:lat_i) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance"),
        ["lat" => $lat, "lng" => $lng, "lat_i" => $lat]);
```

That's enough.

Comment: In which version can you put bindings as the second parameter of DB::raw?

Comment: I use it in Laravel 4.2

Comment: In 4.2 you can use bindings as the second parameter in whereRaw(), but not in DB::raw().

In the example above, the bindings are getting passed to select(), not DB::raw().

Comment: I'm getting an error "strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given"

Comment: Ok, apparently (not sure if intended?) but using `$modelClass::select(DB::raw($queryString), $arrayOfParameters)` gives that error. BUT if I use `$modelClass::selectRaw($queryString, $arrayOfParameters)` it's all hunky-dory!

Answer (score 12):

why not?

```
    $latitude = $request->input('latitude', '44.4562319000');
    $longitude = $request->input('longitude', '26.1003480000');
    $radius = 1000000;

    $locations = Locations::selectRaw("id, name, address, latitude, longitude, image_path, rating, city_id, created_at, active,
                         ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(?) ) *
                           cos( radians( latitude ) )
                           * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(?)
                           ) + sin( radians(?) ) *
                           sin( radians( latitude ) ) )
                         ) AS distance", [$latitude, $longitude, $latitude])
        ->where('active', '1')
        ->having("distance", "<", $radius)
        ->orderBy("distance")
        ->get();
```

Comment: This is a 2-year question. `selectRaw` was not available in back then.

Comment: select() takes the bindings

Answer (score 4):

I encountered same issue just recently and the answer is in that error message `mixed named and positional parameters`. In your case, the `:lat` and `:lng` are named parameters while you have `$radius` as positional. So one possible fix to your issue is make use of `havingRaw()` and apply named parameters.

`--havingRaw('distance < :radius', ['radius' => $radius])`

Answer (score 2):

```
$select = <<<SQL
    title,
    lat,
    lng,
    (3959*acos(cos(radians( ? ))*cos(radians(lat))*cos(radians(lng)-radians( ? ))+sin(radians( ? ))*sin(radians(lat)))) AS distance
SQL;

$property = Property::selectRaw($select, [$lat, $lng, $lat])
    ->having('distance', '<', $radius)
    ->orderBy('distance')
    ->take(20)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I ported the nearby search from Doctrine v1 to Laravel, [check it out here.](https://github.com/malhal/Laravel-Geographical)

Just add the `Geographical` trait to the model then you can do:

```
$model->newDistanceQuery($request->query('lat'), $request->query('lon'))->orderBy('miles', 'asc')->get();
```

It works by using selectRaw with bindings like this:

```
$sql = "((ACOS(SIN(? * PI() / 180) * SIN(" . $latName . " * PI() / 180) + COS(? * PI() / 180) * COS(" . $latName . " * PI() / 180) * COS((? - " . $lonName . ") * PI() / 180)) * 180 / PI()) * 60 * ?) as " . $unit;
if($kilometers){
    $query->selectRaw($sql, [$lat, $lat, $lon, 1.1515 * 1.609344]);
}
else{
    // miles
    $query->selectRaw($sql, [$lat, $lat, $lon, 1.1515]);
}
```