# Multi Parameter binding prevent SQL Injection in laravel with DB:raw in WHERE IN clause

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel

How can I bind multiple parameters from different arrays to prevent SQL injection?

```php
$userTypeID = [1,2,3];
$userDeptID = [1,4,6];
$arr = join(",",$arr);
DB::select("select * from users WHERE userTypeID IN (?,?,?) AND userDeptID IN(?,?,?)");
```

I'm not able to use eloquent because I have a complex query for which I'm using raw queries. So to prevent it from SQL Injection I've to bind the parameters but this isn't working.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to bind parameters to a raw DB query in Laravel that's used on a model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20864872/how-to-bind-parameters-to-a-raw-db-query-in-laravel-thats-used-on-a-model)

Comment: What is complex about your query that is preventing you using Eloquent?

Comment: `DB::select("select * from users WHERE userTypeID IN (?,?,?) AND userDeptID IN(?,?,?)", $arr);` How about this? You tried this? Also, can you explain what your problem is?

Comment: Yes, sonam81 i tried that but parameters count issue occurred for that..

Comment: Peppermintology, yes I actually the graph is complex because the result is populated into graph data and other reporting sections. so that's why if we go for eloquent right I would be a little bit expensive and challenging as well...

Comment: the bindings would be in an array, not a single string

Comment: yes, that is the when i'm going to convert array to string then query become
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID IN('1,2,3,4') AND DeptID IN('1,4,6') and got array to string conversion array.
is there any that I convert array into string like this:
[1,2,3] => "1","2","3" OR 1,2,3
when I'm doing this by using implode(',',$arr) then result occur in this format 
'1,2,3'....

Comment: no it needs to be multiple values, that is why it would be an array ... making it a string would be 1 single value, you have 6 parameters there, not 1

Comment: yes, lagbox so how can i do that brother any solution because I'm totally stuck at this stage. try all the solution.

Comment: by passing an array of all the values you want to bind to those parameters; an array with 6 elements ... not sure what part is holding you up about that

Comment: yes, actually in my application i've have 6 multiple selectors which accept the value in array then in my function I'm using laravel DB:raw query to the data from database on the behalf of that filter and populate that data in different reporting section. To prevent from SQL Injection I have to bind the parameters as well all the parameters values are in array and my SQL query I use that parameter with "WHERE IN"clause.

Answer (score 1):

Use `array_merge` to merge two arrays to single. And pass it to `DB::select()` as second parameter.

```
$userTypeID = [1,2,3];
$userDeptID = [1,4,6];
$arr = array_merge($userTypeID, $userDeptID);

DB::select("SELECT * FROM users WHERE userTypeID IN (?,?,?) AND userDeptID IN(?,?,?)", $arr);
```

EDIT:
OR alternatively, you can also use `OPENJSON` in SQL-Server to convert json object to row. This can then be used in `IN` operator to extract required data.

```
$userDeptID = (array) json_encode([1,4,6]);
DB::select("SELECT * FROM users WHERE userTypeID IN (SELECT value FROM OPENJSON(?))", $userDeptID);
```

Comment: yes, Sonam it is working but is there any other possibility by using name binding because in this case I've six filter parameters and each parameter is used in subquery each subquery and I have a total of 7 subqueries. So if I do array_merge then it might be expensive for me.

Comment: @SyedarslanAhmed Which db are you using?

Comment: i'm using the Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: @SyedarslanAhmed I have added new ways to get data. Checkout if it helps.

Comment: No, Sonam81 its not working.

Comment: What seems to be the problem with new query?

Comment: prepareBindings() must be of the type array

Comment: Maybe try casting to array. `$userDeptID = (array) json_encode([1,4,6]);
`

Comment: [SQL Server]Invalid object name 'OPEN_JSON'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240615/discussion-between-sonam81-and-syedarslan-ahmed).

Comment: Its OPENJSON. Updated.

Comment: [SQL Server]Invalid object name 'OPENJSON'.