# How to use WHERE NOT IN in DB:Raw Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, raw

How to use WHERE NOT IN in DB:raw Laravel?

Here's my sample code

```
$query = DB::select(DB::raw("... WHERE ID NOT IN (:ids) ..", array( 'ids' => "1,2,3" )));
```

I also tried this

```
$ids = "'1','2','3'";
$query = DB::select(DB::raw("... WHERE ID NOT IN (:ids) ..", array( 'ids' => $ids )));
```

Comment: You say you "can't use" it. Why is this the case? What is the issue? You have to give us an error log or something to work with.

Comment: Sorry, I mean, how to use NOT IN condition in DB:raw? @wandering-geek

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to bind parameters to a raw DB query in Laravel that's used on a model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20864872/how-to-bind-parameters-to-a-raw-db-query-in-laravel-thats-used-on-a-model)

Answer (score 1):

You would need to do use `setBindings` to bind your params like below

```
$query = DB::select(DB::raw("... WHERE ID NOT IN (:ids) .."))
    ->setBindings(['ids' => $ids]);
```

Answer based on docs https://laravel.com/api/10.x/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_setBindings

Comment: It says "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: #### Unknown column 'ids' in 'where clause'"

Comment: I updated my answer, chanaged `ids` to `:ids` in the where clause

Comment: Checked also other SO answer with the same concern: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20873009/13933721

Comment: In the accepted answer, author did not need to add `:` in the code.

Comment: Not working on my end. Truncated incorrect DECIMAL value: '24,1' when ['ids' => '24,1']

Comment: That is because `$ids` is not an array based on your question. it should be `$ids = [24, 1];` not `$ids = "'1','2','3'";`

Comment: At least that is the reason that I thought of.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the error, "Unknown column 'ids' in 'where clause'", suggests that the database engine is treating 'ids' as a column name rather than as a parameter placeholder.

The below change can probably work:

```
$query = DB::select(DB::raw("... WHERE ID NOT IN (?)"));
$results = $query->setBindings([$ids]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it. Thank you for your answers, but I use this solution:

```
$ids = [1,2,3];
//ids = [''] if ids is empty
$bindStr = trim(str_repeat('?,',count($ids)),',');
$query = DB::select(DB::raw("... WHERE ID NOT IN ({$bindStr})"), $ids);
```

Comment: Just in case: be careful with formatting string into SQL-query by yourself. It may lead to SQL-Injection if user can somehow pass his malformed input to this string.