# Laravel query builder two tables in left join

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have the following query which I'm trying to convert into Laravel's query builder so I can take advantage of automatic escaping etc.

```sql
SELECT subjects.name, report_comments.comment
FROM subjects
LEFT JOIN (report_comments, library_comments) ON subjects.id = library_comments.subject_id
AND report_comments.library_comment_id = library_comments.id
AND report_comments.report_id = 1
```

Effectively what the query says is 'get the names of all the subjects, and if they have a matching report_comment (via the intermediate `library_comments` table), return that along with the subject' (a subject has either one or zero report_comments for the given criteria). The query works if I run it directly in MySQL and returns the results I'd expect. The `report_comment.report_id = 1` is hard-coded at the moment but will eventually be a placeholder so that any `report_id` can be passed in.

So far I've managed to get:

```php
DB::table('subjects')->select(['subjects.name', 'report_comments.comment'])->leftJoin('report_comments', function ($join) {
$join->on('subjects.id', '=', 'library_comments.subject_id')
->on('report_comments.library_comment_id', '=', 'library_comments.id')
->on('report_comments.report_id', '=', '1');
})
```

If I add `toSql` the result is:

```sql
select `subjects`.`name`, `report_comments`.`comment` from `subjects` left join `report_comments` on `subjects`.`id` = `library_comments`.`subject_id` and `report_comments`.`library_comment_id` = `library_comments`.`id` and `report_comments`.`report_id` = `1`
```

This is almost what I want, except it fails because the `library_comments` table is not mentioned at all:

```php
Illuminate/Database/QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'library_comments.subject_id' in 'on clause' (SQL: select `subjects`.`name`, `report_comments`.`comment` from `subjects` left join `report_comments` on `subjects`.`id` = `library_comments`.`subject_id` and `report_comments`.`library_comment_id` = `library_comments`.`id` and `report_comments`.`report_id` = `1`)'
```

What I need to do is tell the `leftJoin` function about `report_comments` *and* `library_comments`, but there doesn't seem to be any way to do this. I tried:

`leftJoin(['report_comments', 'library_comments'], function($join)`

on a guess that Laravel might convert an array of table names into `(report_comments, library_comments)`, but that didn't work and gave me the following warning:

```php
PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion in /home/paul/sites/report-assistant/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Grammar.php on line 39
```

Is there a way to pass multiple tables into `leftJoin`, or do I need to completely rewrite the query in order to work with Laravel's query builder?

I'm using `laravel/framework` version 5.8.21 and all my dependencies are up to date (`composer update && npm update`).

Comment: have a look at these they were of help to me with a similar issue [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16848987/a-join-with-additional-conditions-using-query-builder-or-eloquent) and [laracast](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/where-clause-in-eloquent-join)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of tinkering, I managed to find the answer in two parts:

First, I had to tweak this part of the join:

```php
on('report_comments.report_id', '=', '1')
```

and replace it with:

```php
where('report_comments.report_id', '=', '1')
```

If I didn't do this, Laravel would quote `1` with backticks, causing MySQL to interpret it as a column name.

The other change was to use `DB::raw`, which I was trying to avoid but I don't think it's too bad in this situation because I'm passing a hardcoded string rather than user input (or anything influenced by user input). The `leftJoin` now looks like:

```php
leftJoin(DB::raw('(report_comments, library_comments)')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `BD::raw`

write query like this and It will work

```
 DB::table('subjects')->select(['subjects.name, report_comments.comment'])->leftJoin(DB::raw('(report_comments, library_comments)'), function ($join) {
$join->on('subjects.id', '=', 'library_comments.subject_id')
->on('report_comments.library_comment_id', '=', 'library_comments.id')
->on('report_comments.report_id', '=', '1');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work but i assume it will be somthing along these lines, hopefully you get something out of it.

Basically added a check to see if the relationship exists if it does then join it.

```
Subject::select('subjects.name, report_comments.comment')
    ->leftJoin('library_comments', 'subjects.id, '=', library_comments.subject_id')
    ->leftJoin('report_comments', function($join){

          if(report->library->relationship){
              $join->on('report_comments.library_comment_id', '=', 'library_comments.id')
              ->where('report_comments.report_id', '=', '1');
          }

})
```