# join with multiple conditions in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to join two tables using more than one condition. The following query is not working because of the second join condition.

```
 $all_update = DB::table('posts as p')
      ->join('cprefs as c','p.qatype', '=', 'c.qatype')
      ->where('c.wwide', '=', 'p.wwide') //second join condition
      ->where('c.user_id', $u_id)
      ->where('p.arank', 1)
      ->get();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A JOIN With Additional Conditions Using Query Builder or Eloquent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16848987/a-join-with-additional-conditions-using-query-builder-or-eloquent)

Comment: And what is the error message that you're receiving?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `where()` functions expects the last parameter to be a parameter where as you are passing in a column name.

To compare two columns you should use the `whereColumn` method.

With that in mind, you could also write your code like below:

```
$all_update = DB::table('posts as p') 
 ->join('cprefs as c','p.qatype', '=', 'c.qatype')
 ->whereColumn('c.wwide', '=', 'p.wwide') //second join condition
 ->where('c.user_id', $u_id) 
 ->where('p.arank', 1) 
 ->get();
```

However, this would only work properly if the the join is an `INNER JOIN` which is true in your case.

The correct method to add multiple join clauses is as below

```
$all_update = DB::table('posts as p') 
->join('cprefs as c', function($q) {
    $q->on('p.qatype', '=', 'c.qatype')
       ->on('c.wwide', '=', 'p.wwide'); //second join condition
}) 
->where('c.user_id', $u_id) 
->where('p.arank', 1) 
->get();
```

Just use this one.

Answer (score 0):

You need the keyword join to use multiple join condition. Irrespective of table.

```
 $all_update = DB::table('posts as p')
  ->join('cprefs as c','p.qatype', '=', 'c.qatype')
  ->join('cprefs as c2','p.wwide', '=', 'c2.wwide') //second join condition
  ->where('c.user_id', $u_id)
  ->where('p.arank', 1)
  ->get();
```

Comment: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'c'

Comment: can you try the edited one. as the alias name were same in the previous one

Comment: The output will have redundant data, because you are joining the table two times, each time with a different column.