# Left Join with Multiple on clause Eloquent Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have the following mysql query

```
select * from operatories o
left join apts ap on o.location = ap.Location and o.operatory = ap.Operatory;
```

I also have two models

```
class Operatories extends Model
{
    public function operatories()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Appointment', 'Location', 'location');
    }
}
```

Appointments:

```
class Appointment extends Model
{
    public function operatories()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Operatories', 'operatory', 'Operatory');
    }
}
```

In my controller I am trying to write the mysql query,

this is what I have so far

```
$arrOperators   =   Operatories::leftJoin('appointment', function ($join) {
    $join->on('appointments.location','=','operatories.location');
})
```

does anyone know how to write multiple on clause?

Comment: Not something I know about, so perhaps a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16848987/a-join-with-additional-conditions-using-query-builder-or-eloquent, but have a check first.

Comment: Did you check this other answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/16849231/7117697